# Rails, select last n characters from a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a string "foo bar man chu" and I want to select the last 5 characters from it.

The regex expression `/.{5}$/` does the job of selecting them, but how do I save them to a string in Rails? `gsub(/.{5}$/,'')` removes them, kind of the opposite of what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `match` method will return the result of attempting to match the string with the regular expression

```
result = "foo bar man chu".match(/.{5}$/)

puts result
=> "n chu"
```

If the regular expression is not matched, then `nil` will be returned.